# Laravel SUM of multiple fields return null with raw query

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, eloquent

The following is my query :

```
 $sales = DB::table('sales')
        ->leftJoin('category_sales', 'category_sales.sale_id', '=', 'sales.id')
        ->leftJoin('department_sales', 'department_sales.sale_id', '=', 'sales.id')
        ->leftJoin('store_configs', 'store_configs.id', '=', 'sales.store_config_id')
        ->select('sales.date',
            DB::raw('store_configs.store_dba'),
            DB::raw('sales.id'),
            DB::raw('(sales.taxable + sales.non_taxable + category_sales.amount + department_sales.amount) as total_sales'),
            DB::raw('0.0825*(sales.taxable + category_sales.amount + department_sales.amount) as total_tax'))
        ->groupBy('date')->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

I get the right value when I have values on `category_sales and department_sales` table. Lets say, I do not have any `amount value for the sales_id in category_sales` table, the final result for `total_sales` and `total_tax` is null.

My question is : how would I still sum the values of fields if the data is present ?

```
taxable, non_taxable, and amount'
```

in `category_sales and department_sales`
are integer with `defaults` to `0`

My table structure just for an idea and is similar with department_sales:

```
CREATE TABLE `category_sales` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`sale_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `category_sales_category_id_index` (`category_id`),
KEY `category_sales_sale_id_index` (`sale_id`),
CONSTRAINT `category_sales_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `category_sales_sale_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `sales` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: So you want to see "0" instead of null in case if there is no data? Is there a type on your question?

Comment: Lets say, if any of the field is null or empty or is not present either I need to get sum of those fields that have values .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap nullable fields into IFNULL() function, something like this:

```
DB::raw('(IFNULL(sales.taxable,0)
 + IFNULL(sales.non_taxable,0)
 + IFNULL(category_sales.amount,0)
 + IFNULL(department_sales.amount,0)
) as total_sales'),
DB::raw('0.0825*(IFNULL(sales.taxable,0) 
 + IFNULL(category_sales.amount,0)
 + IFNULL(department_sales.amount,0)) as total_tax'))
```

Comment: Thanks @amaksr . I had tried If before, but was not doing in proper way.

Comment: your answer got me moving form that stage, but I have been crying to get through another step with another question here in stackoverflow,  if you get some time, I would appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776675/laravel-query-builder-sum-returns-multiplied-values
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use IFNULL to check and convrrt to 0

```
 DB::raw('(IFNULL(sales.taxable,0)+ IFNULL(sales.non_taxable,0) + IFNULL(category_sales.amount,0) + IFNULL(department_sales.amount,0)) as total_sales'),
```

Rather I recommend you to change your db column structure, set default value as zero and dont allow null values.